Insert Data from an existing table to a new table - clickhouse
I have a table called event_source which has lot of data which is a mix of data from multiple sources produced by multiple teams and i want to create tables specific to each team.
This table gets data from kafka and stores the whole data json as string
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW events.event_source_mv TO events.event_source ( `message` String ) AS SELECT message AS message FROM events.kafka_engine;

CREATE TABLE events.event_source ( `ingest_time` DateTime DEFAULT now() CODEC(LZ4HC(9)), `message` String CODEC(LZ4HC(9)) ) ENGINE = MergeTree PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(ingest_time) ORDER BY ingest_time TTL toDateTime(ingest_time) + toIntervalMonth(6) SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192, storage_policy = 'hot_to_cold';

I am trting to create MATERIALIZED VIEW like following which updates new incoming data
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW event_source_business1_mv TO event_source_business1
  AS SELECT
    ingest_time as ingest_time,
    JSONExtractString(message,'source') as source,
    JSONExtractString(message,'eventName') as event_name,
    JSONExtractString(JSONExtractString(message,'entityContext'),'type') as ec_type,
    JSONExtractString(JSONExtractString(message,'additionalInfo'),'ip_address') as ai_ip_address
FROM event_source;

What is the best way to get the old data in the new table i.e. previous data present in source
given the data in source table is close to 6TB uncompressed spanning over 3 months, would be glad to provide extra data if needed
tried using insert(something along the lines of insert into event_source_business1 from event_source where date>3months) but its failing inbetween after sometime, is there a better way

Can you clarify your question alittle? Are you trying to backfill data into a new table and your INSERT INTO SELECT is failing?
If this is the case, the INSERT INTO SELECT is probably the easiest. Any reason you can't simply issue multiple requests, each dealing with a smaller time range than 6TB in one go?

Yes I am trying to backfill the data, i am not sure why its failing, i can try running smaller time ranges(this is my backup option), i was hoping to see if theres a different alternative

You can move the partitions https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/partition#move-partitionpart but not if you need to transform it

this talks about moving data between volumes like hot to cold storage, can it also work for different tables

INSERT ... SELECT is the way to go for moving data.
OFFSET and LIMIT could be leveraged to slice the big chunk into smaller pieces.
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings#offset
I would probably run some loops to do the backfill.

I'd only add you would be best trying to ensure you can filter in chunks based on the primary key for efficiency and to avoid linear scans on each chunk.

agreed i will use primary key and in the given example above its the ingest time, i can try inserting day wise, but should i be using skip? what if query is
insert into newtable select * from old table where primary key is between time range(1 day)
is skip needed in this scenario?
